# Getting a value from an associative array.

Tags: php, arrays, get, key, associative

I'm a beginner and for some reason I'm having trouble with this one. I have the following associative array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name_type] => UnixName
        [name] => charles
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name_type] => DNSFQDN
        [name] => charles.mydnsdomain.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name_type] => DNSDomain
        [name] => mydnsdomain.com
    )

)
```

The problem is that these arrays are never in the same order and the keys are named the same. I only need the DNSFQDN. When I loop through the array how can I check to see if the DNSFQDN value is there, and then retrieve charles.mydnsdomain.com so I can put it into a varible.

I've tried functions like in_array and array_search but I'm having trouble with these as I'm working strictly with associative arrays.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful;

```
$input = array(
    array(
        'name_type' => 'UnixName',
        'name' => 'charles'
    ),
    array(
        'name_type' => 'DNSFQDN',
        'name' => 'charles.mydnsdomain.com'
    ),
    array(
        'name_type' => 'DNSDomain',
        'name' => 'mydnsdomain.com'
    )
);

$domain = $input[array_search('DNSFQDN', array_column($input, 'name_type'))]['name'];
echo $domain; exit;
// output; charles.mydnsdomain.com
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

its simple try bellow ..i hope it will help

```
<?php
$test_array = array(
        array('name_type'=>'UnixName','name'=>'charles'),
        array('name_type'=>'DNSFQDN','name'=>'charles.mydnsdomain.com'),
        array('name_type'=>'DNSDomain','name'=>'mydnsdomain.com'),
    );

foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['name_type']=='DNSFQDN'){
        echo "Domain Name :";
        echo $value['name'];
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate array using foreach loop.

```
<?php
    $array_values = array(
    array('name_type'=>'UnixName','name'=>'charles'),
    array('name_type'=>'DNSFQDN','name'=>'charles.mydnsdomain.com'),
    array('name_type'=>'DNSDomain','name'=>'mydnsdomain.com'),
    );
    foreach ($array_values as $value) {
        if($value['name_type']=='DNSFQDN'){
            echo "DNSDomain = ".$value['name'];
        }
    }
?>
```